# 301 Redirect vs Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site that was hosted by someone else all the web pages were .html files.  I am now hosting the site and have changed it to a wordpress site.  The domain has not changed but obviously all the pages have.  What is the best way to redirect all the .html pages to the main url?

Answer (score 11):

`301 Redirect` in an `.htaccess` does not require the mod_rewrite library.  It's a much simpler way to redirect, but it doesn't have the flexibility and power you get using the Rewrite rules.  If you have a 1-1 mapping with explicit urls you can use the Redirect:

```
Redirect 301  /path/file.html http://new.site.com/newpath.php
```

If you're trying to do wild card matching of a number of similar patterns using regular expressions you'll need to use Rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ http://new.site.com/$1.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Here's a pretty good overview of the 2 methods: http://www.ksl-consulting.co.uk/301-redirect-examples.html

Comment: What if I want to redirect WWW and non-WWW version? Can I do this without RewriteRule or mod_rewrite library?

Comment: @Boris_yo no, you need rewrite conditions if you're trying to catch the protocol http vs. https

Comment: Not really a protocol but WWW and non-WWW

Comment: @Boris_yo you can't catch domian / host names either with Redirect, only a RewriteRule with a RewriteCondition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.com[nc]` 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`

Answer (score 0):

There is also RedirectMatch that also does wild card matching of similar patterns using regular expressions.  The choice depends on just what you need to do.

Rewrite is complex - learning curve - but you can serve alternative urls without giving a HTML code and things that seem imposible. But with great power comes complexity and lots of bugs.

If you are only doing a simple redirection - possibly matching some urls - redirect is the way to go.

When you can't do it with Redirect, you will probably want to start learning Mod_Rewrite.